# 'Conversion from string "" to type 'Boolean' is not valid' in LINQ group by query

Tags: vb.net, linq

I have a table with a single column 'Name' where I want to count the no. of occurrence of each values in the column,

```
+-------+
| Name  |
+-------+
| Sam   |
| Sam   |
| Megan |
| Andy  |
| Andy  |
+-------+
```

I'm using the below LINQ query,

```
Dim query = From row In dtMain.
            Group row By Name= row.Field(Of String)("Name") Into Variable=
            Group Select New With {
            Key VariableName,
           .Frequency = Variable.Count(Function(r) r.Field(Of String)("Name"))
            }
```

I get the below error on execution of the above query,

'Conversion from string "" to type 'Boolean' is not valid'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Enumerable.Count` expects a boolean comparison since it wants to know what it must count, but you are providing a `String` here:

```
Variable.Count(Function(r) r.Field(Of String)("Name"))
```

So you could for example count a specific name in this way:

```
Variable.Count(Function(r) r.Field(Of String)("Name") = "Joe")
```

But you want the group-size so you just need to use `Variable.Count()`.

```
Dim query = From row In dtMain.AsEnumerable
            Group row By Name = row.Field(Of String)("Name")
            Into Variable = Group Select New With {
                Key Name,
                    .Frequency = Variable.Count()
            }
```

Note that `Variable` is a bad name since it doesn't say anything about it's type or purpose, `NameGroup` is better.